# Differences between Capistrano and Mina gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are the main difference between Capistrano and Mina gem. Why should I choose Mina over Capistrano.?

Comment: https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/faster-web-application-deployments-using-mina-instead-of-capistrano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Difference is that

> Compare Mina to the  Capistrano, where each command is ran
>   separately on their own SSH sessions. Mina only creates *one* SSH